# Update data point labels in bokeh plot

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I use bokeh in an ipython notebook and would like to have a button next to a plot to switch on or off labels of the data points. I found a *solution* using `IPython.html.widgets.interact`, but this solution resets the plot for each update including zooming and padding

This is the minimal working code example:

```python
from numpy.random import random
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from IPython.html.widgets import interact

def plot(label_flag):
    p = figure()
    N = 10
    x = random(N)+2
    y = random(N)+2
    labels = range(N)
    p.scatter(x, y)
    if label_flag:
        pass
        p.text(x, y, labels)

    output_notebook()
    show(p)

interact(plot, label_flag=True)
```

p.s. If there is an easy way to do this in matplotlib I would also switch back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource` to store and change the plot's data I was able to achieve what I wanted.

One caveat is, that I found no way to make it work w/o refresh w/o calling `output_notebook` twice in two different cells. If I remove one of the two `output_notebook` calls the gui of the `tools`-button looks breaks or changing a setting also results in a reset of the plot.

```python
from numpy.random import random
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from IPython.html.widgets import interact
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
output_notebook()

## <-- new cell -->

p = figure()

N = 10
x_data = random(N)+2
y_data = random(N)+2
labels = range(N)
source = ColumnDataSource(
    data={
        'x':x_data,
        'y':y_data,
        'desc':labels
    }
) 
p.scatter('x', 'y', source=source)
p.text('x', 'y', 'desc', source=source)
output_notebook()

def update_plot(label_flag=True):
    if label_flag:
        source.data['desc'] = range(N)
    else:
        source.data['desc'] =  ['']*N
    show(p)

interact(update_plot, label_flag=True)
```

Comment: double output_notebook() necessary because of this: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2024